# Improve Random Forest Algorithm for classification of U2R attack

Tags: java, data-mining, weka, random-forest

I am doing project in network intrusion detection system. KDD CUP'99 data set is my input data set.I used weka packages in my java code.I use "NETBEANS" for doing code of java.Four types of attack in KDD CUP'99 data set such as DOS,PROBE, U2R, R2L & I work on this attacks. DOS, PROBE & R2L'S classification rate is very good using Random Forest algorithm.But I want to increase classification rate of U2R attack.How to improve random forest algorithm? For increase the classification rate of U2R attack..Please give me ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this data set. It's flawed. http://www.kdnuggets.com/news/2007/n18/4i.html

> As a result, we strongly recommend that
>
> (1) all researchers stop using the KDD Cup '99 dataset,
>
> (2) The KDD Cup and UCI websites include a warning on the KDD Cup '99
>   dataset webpage informing researchers that there are known problems
>   with the dataset, and
>
> (3) peer reviewers for conferences and journals
>   ding papers (or even outright reject them, as is common in the network
>   security community) with results drawn solely from the KDD Cup '99
>   dataset.

Let me repeat **this data set must not be used for network-intrusion detection**. It does not reflect *reality*, it's simulated and old data. It looks ***nowhere* like any current attack pattern** anyway.

Other than that, the files should be ASCII text files. With good tools you don't need to extract it, because they can be decompressed on the fly (in fact, your webbrowser might be using this compression on the fly with some webservers)

For anything other than runtime benchmarking, don't use it.

Comment: you are right @Anony-Mousse.I read about kdd cup'99 .Than which data set can I use.which data set best for network intrusion detection system?Please suggest me.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such data set being widely available. The problem is that **attacks change quickly**. Using a data set more than half a year old will not yield a working system. IMHO, you even need "early warning" data. Once you have labeled data, the attack should already be blocked off by trivial filter rules and software bugfixes.

Comment: I do not know whether there is other data set for network intrusion but you can find network data sets at http://crawdad.cs.dartmouth.edu